# HTML Canvas create vertical dashed line

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, canvas

I have a basic canvas element **fillRect**.

How to add dashes to below elements.

```
ctx.fillStyle = '#40516a';
ctx.fillRect(70, 1, 5, 180);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = '#40516a';
ctx.fillRect(70, 1, 5, 180);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried below code but not working.

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.setLineDash([5, 15]);
```

I want output like below.

[image: expected output]

Comment: @ Temani Afif, i want vertical dash line.

Comment: updated the duplicate, made a wrong copy past (https://jsfiddle.net/s5m1k4tw/)